# List of common abbreviations

Tags: discussion, faq, terminology

I've been actively using a few StackExchange sites for some months now, and it seems common for some users (especially the more experienced ones) to use abbreviations in their questions, answers and comments. These go from `AFAIK`, which are known and used elsewhere, to others like `OP` and `CW`, which appear to be internal to the StackExchange network. Others appear to be internal to `SFF` (this site).

While most abbreviations might seem natural to experienced users and native English speakers, I think there should be a list of common abbreviations for everybody to read. In my opinion, this should *not* be a question in meta, but a part of the FAQ.

In any case, [this question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/list-of-common-abbreviations-noad-esl-pie) in English Language & Usage meta seems to be a good read (at least the part of the StackExchange abbreviations), but it would be good to have a list here.

The reason for this post is that somebody [replied to a comment of mine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7599/why-isnt-there-ever-any-mention-of-the-americas-in-harry-potter#comment21192_11460) and used a name or abbreviation I've never seen before (`WOMBAT`), so I couldn't really judge whether his reply was well-founded. I already knew what `FYI` means, but, as I said before, this might not be natural for people with English as a second language, just as `OP` is not natural for new users.

If your answer is "Just google it": Yes, I could waste a few minutes using a search engine, but it'd be way better if there was a list of abbreviations as part of `SFF`. Actually, it'd make it more self-contained, which can only be positive.

(...besides, a google search for "wombat" just shows a bunch of Australian marsupials)

Comment: I've seen OP used elsewhere, and I think it actually fits better on forums/discussion sites; here there is occasionally confusion as to whether it's the OP of the question or the answer (when used in comments on an answer).

Comment: @Janoma - you picked a really poor example, sorry. WOMBAT is an in-universe term from Harry Potter, and has nothing to do with your (otherwise very valid and good) question

Comment: @DVK What do you mean by *in-universe*? I said "name or abbreviation" because I didn't know what WOMBAT was at all (or if it was an abbreviation). And it's a perfectly valid example, since I'm asking from general abbreviations of English expressions to abbreviations specific to StackExchange, Science Fiction & Fantasy and even to subtopics of this website.

Comment: @Janoma - I mean an abbreviation used by the author to be used in texts within the universe. WOMBAT is not a "common Engilsh" or "SE" or "SFF" abbreviation. It's an abbreviation invented by JK.Rowling to be used by her characters in the books or other HP materials. (and the reason your Google failed is because you didn't include "harry potter" in the [query](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&noj=1&site=webhp&q=wombat+harry+potter) - if you did it's the first link)

Comment: @DVK That's why I included abbreviations for "subtopics of this website", like Harry Potter. In any case, I don't remember reading "WOMBAT" in the books. Also, "in-universe" should have its own explanation, then, because I thought it referred to the books only, and not additional material.

Comment: See also http://www.lspace.org/faqs/acronym-faq.g.html on Discworld-related acronyms.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

***Please avoid using abbreviations, especially on the main site. The following list is meant to be helpful if you encounter an unfamiliar abbreviation. It does not constitute an invitation to use these abbreviations.***

See also: [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

## Common abbreviations

The following is a list of acronyms and abbreviations common to the Internet, to Stack Exchange or to speculative fiction:

- AFAIK — as far as I know
- AKA — also known as
- ASOIAF — [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire)
- BSG — [*Battlestar Galactica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica) [battlestar-galactica](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica)
- CW — [community wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/); a post "owned" by the entire community rather than just the original poster
- DV — downvote
- EL&U, ELU — [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
- EU — Expanded Universe, works which tell a story in a universe but were not made by that universe's original creator. Most often used to refer to Star Wars.
- FGITW — [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), when several nearly-identical answers are posted within minutes
- FotR — *The Lord of the Rings* volume 1: [*The Fellowship of the Ring*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring)
- FWIW - For what it's worth
- FYI — for your information
- HHGTTG — [*The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) [hitchhikers-guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitchhikers-guide)
- GoT — [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones)
- GR — General reference, a [former](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/should-we-burninate-general-reference) close reason (“This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.”)
- HNQs — [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), a list of 'hot' (many votes and views) questions across the Stack Exchange network; a question reaching this list generally means plenty of rep for all involved
- HP — [*Harry Potter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter) ([see below](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/list-of-common-abbreviations/1532#1532)) [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter)
- IANAL — I am not a lawyer
- IIRC — if I recall correctly
- IIUC — if I understand correctly
- IMHO/IMnsHO — in my [not so] humble opinion.
- IOW — in other words
- ISTR — I seem to remember/recall
- IYKWIM — if you know what I mean
- JKR — [J.K. Rowling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._K._Rowling)
- Lit — [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)
- LotR — [*Lord of the Rings*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_%28disambiguation%29) [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings)
- MCU — [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe)
- Movies, M&TV — [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)
- MSE — [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), the “main meta” or “meta meta” site of the network, for discussing meta topics that affect all its sites
- MSO — [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), the “meta” site of the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (SO) site, for discussing meta topics that affect the SO site
- NaRQ — Not a real question, a [former](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv) close reason (“It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.”)
- NC — Not constructive, a [former](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv) close reason (“This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.”)
- OP — original poster / original post; the author of a given question or the question post itself
- OT — off-topic (usually; beware, some people use it for on-topic!)
- PKD — [Philip K. Dick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_K._Dick) [philip-k-dick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philip-k-dick)
- Pterry — [Terry Pratchett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett) [terry-pratchett](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terry-pratchett)
- RAH — [Robert A. Heinlein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein) [robert-heinlein](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robert-heinlein)
- retcon — [retroactive continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retcon):  the alteration of previously established facts in a fictional work
- RotK — *The Lord of the Rings* volume 3: [*The Return of the King*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_King)
- SE — [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/), our growing network of question-and-answer sites on diverse topics from software programming to cooking to photography and gaming
- SF — either Science Fiction or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), one of the *Big Three* stacks of the Stack Exchange network (the other two being Stack Overflow and Super User)
- SF&F, SFF — [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), the name of this site.
- SG — [*Stargate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate) [stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate)

  - SG1 — [*Stargate SG-1*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_SG-1) [stargate-sg1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate-sg1)
  - SGA — [*Stargate Atantis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Atlantis) [stargate-atlantis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate-atlantis)
  - SGU — [*Stargate Universe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Universe) [stargate-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate-universe)
- SO — [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), the programming questions-and-answers site with which it all began; one of the *Big Three* stacks of the Stack Exchange network (the other two being Server Fault and Super User)
- SPaG — spelling, punctuation, and grammar
- ST — [*Star Trek*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek) [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek)

  - ST:DS9 — *Star Trek: [Deep Space 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)* (series 3) [star-trek-ds9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-ds9)
  - ST:ENT — *Star Trek: [Enterprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Enterprise)* (series 5) [star-trek-enterprise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-enterprise)
  - ST:TNG — *Star Trek: [The Next Generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)* (series 2) [star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng)
  - ST:TOS — *Star Trek: [The Original Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)* (series 1) [star-trek-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos)
  - ST:VOY — *Star Trek: [Voyager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager)* (series 4) [star-trek-voyager](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-voyager)
- SU — [Super User](http://superuser.com), one of the *Big Three* sites of the Stack Exchange network (the other two being Stack Overflow and Server Fault)
- SW — [*Star Wars*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars) [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars)

  - AotC — *Star Wars: [Attack of the Clones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones)* (Episode II)
  - ESB — *Star Wars: [The Empire Strikes Back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back)* (Episode V)
  - NH *or* ANH — *Star Wars: [A New Hope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope)* (Episode IV)
  - OT — The Star Wars Original Trilogy (Episodes IV, V, and VI)
  - PT — The Star Wars Prequel Trilogy (Episodes I, II, and III)
  - RotJ — *Star Wars: [The Return of the Jedi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi)* (Episode VI)
  - RotS — *Star Wars: [Revenge of the Sith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith)* (Episode III)
  - ST — The Star Wars Sequel Trilogy (Episodes VII, VIII, and IX)
  - TLJ — *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*
  - TPM — *Star Wars: [The Phantom Menace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace)* (Episode I)
  - TFA — *Star Wars: [The Force Awakens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens)* (Episode VII)
  - TGFFA — "The Galaxy Far, Far Away" (Settings/location of Star Wars)
- TL;DR *or* TLDR — Literally, "Too Long; Didn't Read".  Has evolved to indicate what follows is an executive summary of what is usually a long and wordy answer (or post, in a forum context).
- TPTB — The Powers That Be, the team that runs all the sites, as opposed to "mere mortals" such as regular users and moderators alike [I actually haven't heard this one].  Alternatively, the people behind a specific work, be they writer, director, or show-runner.
- TREU — *[The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe)*. Our main chat room.
- TTT — *The Lord of the Rings* volume 2: [*The Two Towers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Towers)
- UV — upvote
- VLQ — very low quality
- VTC — vote to close
- VTD — vote to delete
- VTLC — vote to leave closed (after a question has already been closed)
- VTRO — vote to re-open
- WOG (or WoG) - Word of God. The person or people responsible for a property's creation. Usually the author/showrunner.
- WoSFoF — Work of SF or Fantasy. Any work, be it written, (moving) images, or any other form.
- WP — [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia)
- YA — Young Adult. Most commonly seen in [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions.

Comment: The Powers That Be can also refer to beings such as angels and gods that sometimes involve themselves in human affairs. ISTR that, in the TV show Angel, that there was some mention of such beings, perhaps in reference to the source of Cordelia's visions.

Comment: CW can also refer to the channel, most notable for being home to most of the *Arrow*-verse.

Comment: TPTB is super familiar to me, as it is a heavily-used acronym in the *Harry Potter* fandom, but there it *does* include moderators, generally. I'm glad SPaG is on this list. When I first came to SFF, I was regularly using "SPaG" as a reason for editing a post; it was several months until someone asked me what the heck SPaG meant! I had just assumed it was a well-known acronym. Never again will I assume, and I now typically try to avoid using lots of acronyms in posts and comments. I do use a lot of acronyms in chat, though. :)

Comment: @Donald.McLean yes,  but it abbv'd as [PTB or 'the powers' not TPTB](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/The_Powers_That_Be)

Answer (score 12):

## Harry Potter

- AK - Avada Kedavra
- COMC - Care of Magical Creatures
- CoS - *Chamber of Secrets* (Book 2)
- DA - Dumbledore's Army
- DADA - Defence Against the Dark Arts
- DD - Dumbledore
- DEs - Death Eaters
- DH - *Deathly Hallows* (Book 7)
- DoM - Department of Mysteries
- DP or TDP — the *Daily Prophet*
- FBAWTFT or FB - *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*
- GoF - *Goblet of Fire* (Book 4)
- HBP - *Half-Blood Prince* (Book 6)
- HoH - Head of House
- HoM - History of Magic
- HP - Harry Potter
- HP:MoR - Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality (a fanfic)
- JKR - J.K. Rowling
- MoM - Ministry of/for Magic
- N.E.W.T.s or NEWTs - Nastily Exhausting Wizarding Tests
- O.W.L.s or OWLs - Ordinary Wizarding Levels
- OotP - *Order of the Phoenix* (Book 5)
- PoA - *Prisoner of Azkaban* (Book 3)
- PS - *Philosopher's Stone* (Book 1, original British title)
- QR - *Quibbler Report*
- QTTA - *Quidditch Through the Ages*
- RoR - Room of Requirement
- Sly - Slytherincess
- S.P.E.W. or SPEW - Society for the Promotion of Elfish Welfare
- SS - *Sorcerer's Stone* (Book 1, US title)
- TBTB - Tales of Beedle the Bard
- TBWL - the Boy Who Lived
- TDP or DP - the *Daily Prophet*
- TWT - Tri-wizard Tournament
- The Chamber - The Chamber of Secrets
- W.O.M.B.A.T.s or WOMBATS - Wizards' Ordinary Magic and Basic Aptitude Test
- WW - *Witch Weekly*
- WWN - Wizarding Wireless Network
- WWW - Weasleys' Wizarding Wheezes

Answer (score 7):

## A Song of Ice and Fire and/or Game of Thrones

**Real life people**

- D&D - Dan Weiss & David Benioff, Producers of the HBO adaptation
- GRRM - George R.R. Martin, writer and creator of the series

**On site**

- TQAT - [The Quill and Tankard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39179/the-quill-and-tankard), the ASOIAF/GoT chatroom for the site

**Books & Show**

- ASOIAF - A Song of Ice and Fire, the name given to the books series.
- AGOT - A Game of Thrones, First book of the series
- ACOK - A Clash of Kings, Second book of the series
- ASOS - A Storm of Swords, Third book of the series
- AFFC - A Feast for Crows, Fourth book of the series
- ADWD - A Dance with Dragons, Fifth book of the series
- ADOS - A Dream of Spring, Seventh book of the series (Planned)
- D&E - Dunk & Egg, Collective name given to a series of Prequels
- GoT - Game of thrones, the name given to the HBO TV Adaptation of the books.
- ToDaE - Tales of Dunk & Egg, official name given to the prequel novella series
- TWOW - The Winds of Winter, Sixth book of the series (Still in progress)
- THK - The Hedge Knight, First novella of Dunk & Egg series
- TSS - The Sworn Sword, Second novella of Dunk & Egg series
- TMK - The Mystery Knight, Third novella of Dunk & Egg series
- TRP - The Rogue Prince, A Prequel novella
- TPATQ - The Princess and the Queen, A Prequel novella
- TWOIAF - The world of Ice and Fire, Companion book

**In-Universe Characters, Events, Organizations and Places**

- AA - Azor Ahai
- AAR - Azor Ahai Reborn
- BB - Bobby B (Robert Baratheon)
- BF - Blackfish (Brynden Tully)
- BR - Bloodraven (Brynden Rivers)
- BwB - Brotherhood without Banners
- CotF - Children of the Forest
- fAegon - Fake Aegon
- FLM - Faceless Men
- FM - First Men
- HoBaW - House of Black and White
- HotU - House of the Undying
- IT - Iron Throne
- JC/JonCon - Jon Connington
- KG - Kingsguard
- KS - Kingslayer
- KL - King's Landing
- KotLt - Knight of the Laughing Tree
- LC - Lord Commander
- LF - Littlefinger
- MFG - Many Faced God
- NK - Night's King
- MMD - Mirri Maz Dur (the Maegi who caused Khal Drogo's death)
- NW - Night's Watch
- PW - Purple Wedding
- QoT - Queen of Thorns
- QoLaB - Queen of Love and Beauty
- RR - Robert's Rebellion
- RW - Red Wedding
- StmtW - Stallion that mounts the World
- TER - Three Eyed Raven (Used in Show)
- TEC/3EC - Three Eyed Crow (Used in books)
- TKitN - The King in the North
- TPTWP - The Prince that was Promised
- ToJ - Tower of Joy
- WotfK - War of the five Kings
- WW - White Walkers
- YG - Young Griff

**Popular Theories and Other Terms**

- AC - After Conquest
- BC - Before Conquest
- BotD - Blood of the Dragon
- GNC - Grand Northern Conspiracy (Theory about Ambitions of Rickard Stark)
- N+A = J

  > Theory that Ned Stark and Ashara Dayne are parents of Jon.
- R+L = J

  > Theory that Rhaegar and Lyanna are parents of Jon.
- SanSan - A fan theory that ships Sansa Stark and Sandor Cleagane together
- T=T

  > A fan theory that Tyrion is a Targaryen
- YMBQ - Younger More Beautiful Queen

  > (A reference to Prophecy made about Cersei's downfall)

Comment: I think in your spoiler under N+A=J you misspelled "wrong."

Answer (score -3):

### Harry Potter Fanfiction [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) [fan-fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan-fiction)

1. ! = The Exclamation Mark or 'Bang' Symbol -- refers to a short form for expressing the presence of a particular trait or defining quality of a character in a story.
2. Ao3 = Archive of our own
3. Daudinn = Death
4. Dramione = Draco has relations with Hermione.
5. Drarry = Draco has relations with Harry.
6. DLP = Dark Lord Potter forums.
7. Ffnet = www.fanfiction.net
8. H/C = Hurt or comfort
9. Indy! = Independent character. Usually used in Lordship fics.
10. MPreg = Male Pregnancy
11. NC17 = Strong violence and adult content.
12. OC = Original character
13. Pairing = Who gets together with whom
14. Pre Het: Used to describe a heterosexual relationship between two characters that does not have an sexual component or actual romantic interest beyond unresolved sexual tension.
15. R&R: Read and review
16. RST = Resolved sexual tension
17. Severitus = Snape is Harry's dad.
18. Slash = Homosexual pairing
19. Slave = Used in BDSM context for submissive
20. TW = Trigger Warning
21. URST = Unresolved Sexual Tension
22. Xeno = Non Human pairing.
23. X-Over = Crossover: fan-fiction which draws from two or more independent fictional universes.

Comment: Many of these seem to be about general fan-fiction and not specifically related to Harry Potter or to the Stack Exchange Network.

Comment: Fanfic id questions are asked often and this might help someone who stumbled upon a common abbreviation. @Skooba

Comment: I've undeleted this answer. No matter how distasteful many of us find (a proportion of) HP fanfiction, it _is_ on-topic for the site, and therefore people should be allowed to use meta to curate resources for it. I did, however, edit this answer to remove one or two particularly problematic entries (I'm not sure if that means what it sounds like, and hope it doesn't, but erring on the side of caution) and some redundant ones.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - My issue with this one is that hardly any of these are common *on our site*. The fact that they're used elsewhere is really none of our business nor of any interest.

Comment: @Valorum Then perhaps others can muck in and improve it. NeoDarwin, would you like to make this answer Community Wiki as other answerers here have done?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I'm not sure he'd be happy with me deleting more than three quarters of his answer.